# smallest float dtype for pandas/minimizing size of transform

Tags: pandas, dataframe, floating-point, data-science

I have a data frame with 17000 columns and 50000 rows of integer values (~1 GB).
I'm dividing each column of the dataframe by the sum of the column (e.g. normalizing the data).

I need to specify the dtype, because otherwise I end up with an output file that > 11GB (default dtype = float64) (!!!)

I tried reducing dtype to float16 (the smallest float dtype I could find for numpy) or even float32.

e.g. dtype = float32 or dtype=float16

```py
thisPart.div(thisPart.sum(axis=1), axis=0, dtype=float32)*(10**6)
```

if I set dtype to float32 or float16, I get

```py
NameError: name 'float32' is not defined
```

if I set dytpe to np.float16 or np.float32, I get

```py
 3 TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

For reference, I'm running a bash.sh script that accesses a conda environment with numpy and pandas

bottom line: *What's the smallest way to transform this matrix without its size exploding?*
**I'm open to other methods besides what I'm doing right now too.**

Comment: Have you tried `thisPart.astype(np.float16)` instead of setting dtype manually?

Comment: Your question does not contain sufficient information to determine what type would suffice for your needs. One would need to know the potential bounds of the sum and the precision with which you need to know its value.

Answer (score 0):

In case your dataframe has low density (it contains a large proportion of zeros, `np.nan` or another value), which is frequently the case with a high number of variables, you could transform your columns into `Sparse` dtypes, greatly reducing memory usage and sometimes speeding up calculation (although that does not appear to be the case here).

Here is a toy example which illustrates the memory and speed difference:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

# Generate binary dense matrix with low density (~90% are zeros)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=50, size=(50_000, 17_000)))
df[df>5] = 0
df[0].value_counts()

# Memory usage ~3.2 GB
print(f"Memory usage:{df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2:.1f} MB")

# Time elapsed 11 seconds
start = time.time()
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0,)*(10**6)
print(f"Time elapsed: {time.time() - start:.2f} seconds")

# Convert to sparse dataframe
sdf = df.copy()
sdf = sdf.astype(pd.SparseDtype(dtype='int8', fill_value=0))

# Memory usage ~0.4 GB (8x reduction)
print(f"Memory usage:{sdf.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2:.1f} MB")

# Time elapsed 69 seconds (>6x increase)
start = time.time()
sdf.div(sdf.sum(axis=1), axis=0,)*(10**6)
print(f"Time elapsed: {time.time() - start:.2f} seconds")
```